# Popup (no ionicPopup) in Ionic + AngularJs + Phonegap

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm starting to development APP with PhoneGap + angularjs + ionic, I can not put a popup with the images above the homeview (sidemenu). Just create a ion-panel but the contents of the main view is moved down.
Can someone please help me? Also how do I hide it and do it only show on click button?

The popup1.png is the background image of the popup that should be at the center of the display and above should insert the image 9.png and text.

Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s74p2go022qz9a6/aaaaa.JPG?dl=0

CODE:

```
<ion-side-menus>
  <!-- Center content -->

  <ion-side-menu-content class="padding">

  <img src="img/popup1.png" style="margin:0 auto; position:center; align: center"width="100%" heght="15%" >

 <ion-panel class="info" id="info1" align="center" width="100%" height="100%">

         <img src="img/9.png" style="padding-top:20px" width="80%" heght="15%" >

        <h1 style="font-size:16px; color:white; padding:15px; text-align: justify">Questa App è stata sviluppata dalla piattaforma IBA.</h1>


  </ion-panel>



   <div class="Home" style="padding:5px">
    <img src="img/home.png" width="95%" heght="10%">

  </div>
```

Comment: Your question is rather vague.  Post a little code and any error messages to get a better help.

Comment: I added the code and a screenshot